# Should I avoid COUNT all together in InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, count, innodb

Right now, I'm debating whether or not to use `COUNT(id)` or "count" columns. I heard that InnoDB `COUNT` is very slow without a `WHERE` clause because it needs to lock the table and do a full index scan. Is that the same behavior when using a `WHERE` clause?

For example, if I have a table with 1 million records. Doing a `COUNT` without a `WHERE` clause will require looking up 1 million records using an index. Will the query become significantly faster if adding a `WHERE` clause decreases the number of rows that match the criteria from 1 million to 500,000?

Consider the "Badges" page on SO, would adding a column in the `badges` table called `count` and incrementing it whenever a user earned that particular badge be faster than doing a `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user_badges WHERE user_id = 111`?

Using MyIASM is not an option because I need the features of InnoDB to maintain data integrity.

Comment: Can't you use `count();` php function to count your results?

Comment: Yes, but that would require fetching all the rows, which is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say avoid, but it depends on what you are trying to do:

- If you only need to provide an estimate, you could do SELECT MAX(id) FROM table.  This is much cheaper, since it just needs to read the max value in the index.
- If we consider the badges example you gave, InnoDB only needs to count up the number of badges that user has (assuming an index on user_id).  I'd say in most case that's not going to be more than 10-20, and it's not much harm at all.

It really depends on the situation.  I probably would keep the count of the number of badges someone has on the main user table as a column (count_badges_awarded) simply because every time an avatar is shown, so is that number.  It saves me having to do 2 queries.

Comment: In the badges example I meant the `/badges` page that shows how many people earned a certain badge. Some badges have been awarded to 100,000 people! Counting 100,000 values is something I would not want to do everything someone views my page.

Comment: If you meant counting how many badges have been issued, doing that live is about as much fun as being stabbed in the eye :)

You want to keep a summary somewhere on the 'badges' table or in memcached.  It's not practical to ask MySQL each time.

Answer (score 5):

**SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename** seems to do a full table scan.

**SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename USE INDEX (colname)** seems to be quite fast if
the index available is NOT NULL, UNIQUE, and fixed-length.  A non-UNIQUE index doesn't help much, if at all.  Variable length indices (VARCHAR) seem to be slower, but that may just be because the index is physically larger.  Integer UNIQUE NOT NULL indices can be counted quickly.  Which makes sense.

MySQL really should perform this optimization automatically.

Comment: Adding USE INDEX(primary) has reduced my query time from an average of 1000ms, down to an average of 40ms. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Performance of `COUNT()` is fine as long as you have an index that's used.

If you have a million records and the column in question is `NON NULL` then a `COUNT()` will be a million quite easily. If `NULL` values are allowed, those aren't indexed so the number of records is easily obtained by looking at the index size.

If you're not specifying a `WHERE` clause, then the worst case is the primary key index will be used.

If you specify a `WHERE` clause, just make sure the column(s) are indexed.

Comment: Really? According to http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/12/01/count-for-innodb-tables/ doing COUNT(id) would still require a full table scan, even if there was an index on `id`.

Comment: @Exception that post is from December 2006. Too long ago to be taken on face value.

Comment: it's an index scan, not a table scan.  But nothing has changed since December 2006.

The reason for the index scan is because InnoDB has a feature called Multiversion Concurrency Control <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control>.  The number of rows depends on the context of your transaction.

Comment: @Morgan Tocker: [MySQL 5.1 was released on Nov 27th, **2008**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mysql)

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I'm aware, I was working for MySQL/Sun Microsytems in Nov 2008 ;)  Nothing in 5.1 (or upcoming 5.5) changes this advice.

Comment: @cletus: Are you sure InnoDB does not index null columns?