# How to avoid the COUNT query Django's paginator does?

Tags: python, django

[Paginator.page()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d8c876190132b03faa11e37b2d9abd6fb2ff48fd/django/core/paginator.py#L70) causes the evaluation of the cached property `count`, which performs a COUNT query on the database.
My problem is that the average query execution time for that COUNT is 1.06 seconds while the average time of the main query is 1.04 seconds. In effect I have a duplicated query.
Is there a way to avoid that COUNT query?

Comment: If I have a choice, I wouldn.t show the count.

Comment: If you want to use paginator, then I don't know any way to avoid the COUNT query.

Comment: See this related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707035/how-to-implement-a-paginator-that-doesnt-call-count

Comment: See this related ticket in Django Code https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8408

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common solution for this problem is to not show the total number of pages. I implemented a custom paginator that doesnt support `count`, `num_pages` neither `page_range`:

```py
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger


class CountlessPage:

    def __init__(self, object_list, page_number: int, page_size: int):
        self._object_list = object_list
        self._page_number = page_number
        self._page_size = page_size
        self._evaluated = False

    @property
    def number(self):
        return self._page_number

    def has_next(self):
        self._evaluate()
        return self._has_next_page

    def has_previous(self):
        return self._page_number > 1

    def has_other_pages(self):
        return self.has_previous() or self.has_next()

    def next_page_number(self):
        if self.has_next():
            return self._page_number + 1
        else:
            raise EmptyPage(_('There is no next page'))

    def previous_page_number(self):
        if self.has_previous():
            return self._page_number - 1
        else:
            raise EmptyPage(_('There is no previous page'))

    def _evaluate(self):
        if self._evaluated: return
        if not isinstance(self._object_list, list):
            self._object_list = list(self._object_list)
        contents = self._object_list
        self._object_list = self._object_list[:self._page_size]
        if len(contents) > len(self._object_list):
            self._has_next_page = True
        else:
            self._has_next_page = False
        self._evaluated = True

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Page %s>' % self._page_number

    def __len__(self):
        self._evaluate()
        return len(self._object_list)

    def __iter__(self):
        self._evaluate()
        return iter(self._object_list)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if not isinstance(index, (int, slice)):
            raise TypeError
        self._evaluate()
        return self._object_list[index]

class CountlessPaginator:
    """A paginator that does not count the total number of pages.

    To count the total number of pages an additional COUNT query
    is needed, use this paginator when peformance is more important.
    It is still possible to navigate to next, previous and first page.
    It's not possible to navigate to an arbitrary page because we
    don't know the number of pages.
    """

    def __init__(self, object_list, per_page: int) -> None:
        self._object_list = object_list
        self._per_page = per_page

    def validate_number(self, number: int):
        """Validate the given 1-based page number."""
        try:
            if isinstance(number, float) and not number.is_integer():
                raise ValueError
            number = int(number)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            raise PageNotAnInteger(_('That page number is not an integer'))
        if number < 1:
            raise EmptyPage(_('That page number is less than 1'))
        return number

    def get_page(self, number: int):
        """
        Return a valid page, even if the page argument isn't a number or isn't
        in range.
        """
        try:
            number = self.validate_number(number)
        except (PageNotAnInteger, EmptyPage):
            number = 1
        return self.page(number)

    def page(self, number: int):
        """Return a Page object for the given 1-based page number."""
        number = self.validate_number(number)
        bottom = (number - 1) * self._per_page
        top = bottom + self._per_page + 1
        return CountlessPage(self._object_list[bottom:top], number, self._per_page)
```