# Performance of a simple MySQL query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, database-performance

I have an index on a table in MySQL:

```
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name      | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+-------+------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| 2011  |          1 | ix_2011_index |            1 | index       | A         |      292691 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL
```

When I try to see how many rows there are in the table,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from mytable.2011;
```

It takes forever. Granted, there are tens of millions of rows in the table, but each row is indexed.

Shouldn't this be almost instantaneous?

I created the table with the default engine:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: Is your table using the InnoDB storage engine (this is the default storage engine on MySQL)?

Comment: InnoDB doesn't cache row counts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/57921400/20860

Comment: @BillKarwin, I didn't tell MySQL which engine to use on installation, so assuming the default

Comment: You can verify with `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable.2011`, and it will show the ENGINE option on the last line. But it's probably InnoDB if you didn't specify.

Comment: @BillKarwin see edited original post. It is InnoDB.

Comment: Okay, that is expected. See the linked answer for the gory details, but the short answer is that SELECT COUNT(*) on a large InnoDB table is not instantaneous.