# How to improve mysql query speed

Tags: sql, mysql, laravel, amazon-rds

When I run this query:

```sql
select count (*) from table_name_1;
```

| count(*) |
| --- |
| 3028840 |

it takes around 50 seconds to get the result.

```sql
explain select count (*) from table_name_1;
```

results:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | table_name_1 | null | index | null | table_name_1_posted_at_index | 5 | null | 2414249 | 100 | Using index |

but when I run this query:

```sql
select count(*) 
from table_name_1 
join table_name_2 on table_name_1.table_name_2_id = table_name_2.id;
```

| count(*) |
| --- |
| 3028840 |

it takes around 5 seconds to complete which is insanely faster than the first query.

```sql
explain select count(*) 
from table_name_1 
join table_name_2 on table_name_1.table_name_2_id = table_name_2.id;
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | table_name_2 | null | index | PRIMARY | table_name_2_last_fetch_at_index | 5 | null | 13393 | 100 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | table_name_1 | null | ref | table_name_1_table_name_2_id_foreign | table_name_1_table_name_2_id_foreign | 8 | table_name_2.id | 354 | 100 | Using index |

Below is the SHOW CREATE.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `table_name_1`
(
    `id`                    bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `table_name_2_id` bigint unsigned                                               DEFAULT NULL,
    `identifier`            varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `permalink`             varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `shortcode`             varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `title`                 text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `description`           text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `duration`              int unsigned                                                  DEFAULT NULL,
    `views`                 int unsigned                                                  DEFAULT NULL,
    `likes`                 int unsigned                                                  DEFAULT NULL,
    `comments`              int unsigned                                                  DEFAULT NULL,
    `platform_type`         varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci                       DEFAULT NULL,
    `posted_at`             timestamp       NULL                                          DEFAULT NULL,
    `media_url`             text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `thumbnail_url`         text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `created_at`            timestamp       NULL                                          DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at`            timestamp       NULL                                          DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `table_name_1_identifier_index` (`identifier`),
    KEY `table_name_1_table_name_2_id_foreign` (`table_name_2_id`),
    KEY `table_name_1_shortcode_index` (`shortcode`),
    KEY `table_name_1_posted_at_index` (`posted_at`) USING BTREE,
    KEY `table_name_1_likes_index` (`likes`),
    KEY `table_name_1_views_index` (`views`),
    KEY `table_name_1_comments_index` (`comments`),
    CONSTRAINT `table_name_1_table_name_2_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`table_name_2_id`) REFERENCES `table_name_2` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 3044455
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
  COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

My question is this, why is the first query not using the fastest index possible but its using a date time index  in my case `posted_at` and is it possible to set what index a table should use by default ( not by USE INDEX) because this database is used in a Laravel WEB APP and loading the page where a count of this specific table is used takes too long to load.

I have tried using `SET INDEX` (setting `PRIMARY`) but it still took around the same time that the first query did, I also tried using `IGNORE INDEX` but still no fix on query speed.

The question related to this one (the mariaDB one) is almost the same case but doesn't necessarily provide guide on how to fix the issue.

Comment: Doesn't `table_name_1` have a primary unique key? Could you give us the table creation queries? See: [SHOW CREATE TABLE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html). Please add them to the question, by editing it, don't add them as comments.

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to PHP or Laravel in any way?

Comment: One of the linked questions is tagged for MariaDB, but in this case the answer is the same for MySQL.

Comment: @NicoHaase the database where im having this problem is the production database of a Laravel project, i thought it might have some relevance maybe the way the table was created or something ( through migration)

Comment: Thank you for adding the creation query. I found that adding something as basic as: `WHERE id > 0`, to your simply query, it already speeds up a lot. It's the difference between a full table scan and actually using an index. You can [find the real reason for this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57926112/3986005). To really understand it, you need to have in-depth knowledge of how databases work. I think that Bill Karwin explains it quite well.